# Javascript why const declaration with curly braces sometime has the = sign within the curly braces?

Tags: javascript, constants

I was studying a project and I saw this kind of pattern:

```
handleValueChange = (e) => {
    const { target: { id, value } = {} } = e || {}; 
    # some code ....
```

I've never seen `=` within `{}` that comes after `const`, and I couldn't find any documentation online.

What is this type of syntax called? 
How does it work?

Comment: It's a default value in destructuring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [Destructuring assignment docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2):

> A variable can be assigned a default, in the case that the value unpacked from the object is `undefined`.

For example:

```js
const {a = 10, b = 5} = {a: 3};

console.log(a); // 3
console.log(b); // 5
```

Here you can see `b` is `undefined` thus while destructuring the default value `5` is used for `b`.

In your case, if `target` is `undefined` while destructuring `e`, then an empty object `{}` will be used instead.

This is needed in cases `e` is `undefined` or `null`, else we will get an error like:

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

```js
const { target: { id, value } } = {};
console.log( id, value )
```

Using **default value** handles this scenario:

```js
const { target: { id, value } = {} } = {};
console.log( id, value )
```

Comment: perfect answer！